# Chef shell script not being run

Tags: ruby, shell, sh, chef-infra

I am using Chef on [Scalarium](http://scalarium.com) to download an agent and run various commands on it. What I'm attempting is to write a shell script in the recipe to perform this.

```
file "/etc/profile.d/blah.sh" do
  content <<-EOH
sudo -sH
<Retrieve file and run some commands>
  EOH
end
```

When I run the recipe in Scalarium, no errors occur, but the commands aren't run either. There's no errors in the commands themselves, as I've run them on my computer.

The recipe is definitely read, as the Chef logs contain `Processing file[/etc/profile.d/blah.sh] on blah.localdomain`.

I've never used Chef before, do I need to do something else to tell it to execute the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
file "/etc/profile.d/blah.sh" do
  mode 0500
  content <<-EOH
sudo -sH
<Retrieve file and run some commands>
  EOH
end

execute "/etc/profile.d/blah.sh"
```

Or, you can put the file retrieval and running of commands directly into your chef recipe:

```
remote_file "/path/to/where/the/file/should/be/saved" do
  source "https://example.com/path/to/where/the/file/comes/from"
end

execute "first command"
execute "second command"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help. How would that work for downloading from a repository for installing as a daemon? Ie the original command was  `echo 'deb http://rep.blah.com etc' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/blah.list`. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: Actually, just using execute works for that too. Thanks for the help!